# Error con git y heroku

Tags: java, html, heroku

[image: Me figura este error al hacer un git heroku main. Ya probe muchas cosas de google y nada funcion]

[image]

El problema surgio el dia de hoy, antes no tenía ningún problema

Comment: Federico, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas las normas de la comunidad y cómo elaborar preguntas que se mantengan en el tiempo sin ser cerradas.

Comment: Hola. Gracias por la recomendación! Me pondre al tanto

Comment: Podrías poner los mensajes de error como texto por favor? Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880

Answer (score 0):

Esto puede ser debido a que la rama `main` a la que intentas subir nuevo código haya pasado a estar protegida o por algún tema de permisos.

Si tienes acceso al panel del sistema de control de versiones que estás usando (`GitHub`,`GitLab`, ...) te recomendaría que mirases por la zona de la configuración para comprobar esto y desprotegerla para implementar los cambios directamente aunque no sea lo recomendable.

Otro flujo de trabajo sería que creases una nueva rama `develop` para desarrollar todas las nuevas features y al subir ambas, al final mergeases la de desarrollo con la `main` para implementar todos esos últimos cambios.

Si eres tú el único colaborador del repositorio es más sencillo la desproteger la rama principal aunque esto no es recomendable si se va a trabajar con otras personas en un repositorio.

Comment: Hola David. Donde encunetro la opcion de desproteger el proyecto?